# Using Spark Streaming for Web Server

Tags: web-services, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to build up a web server that only processes http request (twitter data) from client side, process it (some calculation) and return a response to the client. The only consideration is speed.

I'm thinking of spark streaming but seems that it can't give a response back. Is there a efficient solution? Or are there any other recommendations for the entire framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the solution can be use of Kafka message queue with apache spark streaming.

Kafka has two parts :

```
1] Producer => send messages across network and act as a buffer
2] Consumer => receives messages from producer
```

**The possible design can be** :

```
1] Write producer using javascript/node-js
2] Write consumer in spark streaming program which will consume all the twitter messages sent from front end. Then you can process these message in spaek.

Now to give response back - 
3] Write second producer in spark program and send your processed data to consumer.
4] Now write second consumer in your front end program (javascript/node-js) which will consume processed messages sent by spark streaming.
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks Sumant! Your answer really helped to get a better picture of the whole thing. I find Amazon Kinesis available for the same task and it seems to be much easier, think I'm gonna use it (I'm deploying on Amazon anyway).